# Save variable from console output Javascript/Python/Jinja2

Tags: javascript, python

I am using Trello API to create a card. This works fine but while the script runs it prints a ID variable of the newly created card to the console. I'd like to take this variable and pass it back to my python code. Is this possible? I am using Jinja2 to pass variables from Python to HTML, can I use this here?

This is the output to the console in Chrome, I want to grab the first ID variable so I can work with it in my Python code.

```
{
  "id": "5a46fa28620367df83fe08f7",
  "badges": {
    "votes": 0,
    "attachmentsByType": {
      "trello": {
        "board": 0,
        "card": 0
      }
    },
    "viewingMemberVoted": false,
    "subscribed": false,
    "fogbugz": "",
    "checkItems": 0,
    "checkItemsChecked": 0,
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
var authenticationSuccess = function() {
  console.log('Successful authentication');
};

var authenticationFailure = function() {
  console.log('Failed authentication');
};

window.Trello.authorize({
  type: 'popup',
  name: 'Work Requests App',
  scope: {
    read: 'true',
    write: 'true' },
  expiration: 'never',
  success: authenticationSuccess,
  error: authenticationFailure
});

//console.log(trelloTitle);
//console.log(trelloContent);

var myList = '5a3ec86f7920a6e66b28e4bc';

var creationSuccess = function (data) {
  console.log('Card created successfully.');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

};

//var data = $('#resultsdata').data();
//console.log(trelloId);



var newCard = {
  name: trelloTitle,
  desc: trelloContent,
  // Place this card at the top of our list
  idList: myList,
  idMembers: trelloId,
  pos: 'top'
};


window.Trello.post('/cards/', newCard, creationSuccess);
```

EDIT: I am now using this AJAX method:

```
var creationSuccess = function (data) {
    console.log('Card created successfully.');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    var url = "/ajaxtest";
    $.post(url, {card_id: data.id});
};
```

I am having difficulty passing card_id into my python method:

```
class AjaxTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = card_id
```

I know this is wrong, can anyone help?

Comment: Seems like you printing the JSON object to the console in the `creationSuccess` function. would sending the data there to your Python server do the job for you?

Comment: Yes it would, I am not sure how to just take what I need from the JSON and pass it back to my python code, though.

Comment: you should be able to access the id using `data.id`. then just send it through an AJAX call to the server.

Comment: Thank you, I have not used AJAX before, could you provide an example?

Comment: you're using pure Javascript? not using jQuery or similar libraries?

Comment: Yes that is what the Trello documentation provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete answer:

```
var creationSuccess = function (data) {
  console.log('Card created successfully.');

  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "URL to your server (where you want to send the data)";

  http.open("POST", url, true);

  http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  http.send("card_id=" + data.id);
};
```

This will send the card id as `card_id` to your server (to the URL you specified) through an AJAX call.

This is assuming that you're only using pure Javascript. If you're using jQuery, then making an AJAX call would be much easier. like:

```
var creationSuccess = function (data) {
  console.log('Card created successfully.');
  var url = "URL to your server";
  $.post(url, {card_id: data.id});
};
```

Edit: As for the server code, you could now receive `card_id` like this:

```
class AjaxTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.get('card_id')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I think I've almost got this working, I have updated my post to show my python code - I am not sure how to pass `card_id` into my python method, would you mind taking a look? I will mark this as the answer anyway.

Comment: I'm using Webapp2.

Comment: Thanks for your help!